# Are multiple layers in LSTM gates usefull?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm doing an LSTM cell implementation from scratch and I was thinking of implementing the computation of the gates with multiple neural layers instead of just using the single layer version : `sigmoid(dot(W,concat(a_prev,xt)) + b)`. I can't seem to find any literature on it. Does it work ? Can it converge ?

This the standard LSTM cell forward propagation code that I learned on Andrew Ng's Deep Learning course :

```
concat = np.zeros((n_a + n_x, m))
concat[: n_a, :] = a_prev
concat[n_a :, :] = xt


ft = sigmoid(np.dot(Wf, concat) + bf)
it = sigmoid(np.dot(Wi, concat) + bi)
cct = np.tanh(np.dot(Wc, concat) + bc)
c_next = ft * c_prev + it * cct
ot = sigmoid(np.dot(Wo, concat) + bo)
a_next = ot * np.tanh(c_next)
# Compute prediction of the LSTM cell
yt_pred = softmax(np.dot(Wy, a_next) + by)
```

This the LSTM cell I want to use :

```
concat = np.zeros((n_a + n_x, m))
concat[: n_a, :] = a_prev
concat[n_a:, :] = xt

ft1 = sigmoid(np.dot(Wf1, concat) + bf1)
ft2 = sigmoid(np.dot(Wf2, ft1) + bf2)

it1 = sigmoid(np.dot(Wi11, concat) + bi1)
it2 = sigmoid(np.dot(Wi12, it1) + bi2)

cct1 = np.tanh(np.dot(Wc1, concat) + bc1)
cct2 = np.tanh(np.dot(Wc2, cct1) + bc2)


c_next = ft2 * c_prev + it2 * cct2

ot1 = sigmoid(np.dot(Wo1, concat) + bo1)
ot2 = sigmoid(np.dot(Wo2, ot1) + bo2)

a_next = ot2 * np.tanh(c_next)

# Compute prediction of the LSTM cell
yt_pred1 = softmax(np.dot(Wy1, a_next) + by1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited my question to include the code Im trying to use, does this clear it up ?

Comment: Some research might help. [This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22690/advantages-of-stacking-lstms/22985#22985) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/179817/16534), maybe?!

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to make the gates inside the LSTM cell deeper not stacking the LSTM cells, I know that stacking  enchances the networks capabilities what I was thinking about was creating a more complex LSTM cell.